# Refresh page when localStorage is deleted

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I am building an app in reactjs.

I use JWT in localStorage in order to authenticate the user in every request in the backend.

What I want to do is to logout the user automatically when the localStorage is deleted via cookies from the user OR JWT token expires.

Is it possible to add a listener which is fired when localStorage is deleted?

For now I am doing something like

```
if(!!localStorage.getItem('id_token') && !this.isTokenExpired(token)) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  location.reload(true);
}
```

It works but its not efficient to add these lines of code in every button functions.

So I want a listener which when the localStorage is deleted or expires to fire the above code.

Any advice? Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you attach your logout code to a conditional when you retrieve the localStorage data, so that if its not there you immediately log out the user?

Comment: First of all thank you for your response. This is not what I need. I want to logout him automatically and no when I have the need of localStorage data

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve it by adding an event listener and index.js

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {
  if(!Auth.loggedIn()) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    location.reload(true);
  }
});
```

So when the storage changes I check if the user is logged in and reload the page. When the page is reloaded I logout the user .